# Attempting to use pyserial between applications, yet I get terminal

Tags: python, pyserial

(update)
So I found some documentation on this link
https://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection#Connections_and_signal_levels
If you scroll down you will find a section "S/W: Preventing Linux from using the serial port"  It says "By default Linux will grab the serial port and use it as a terminal."

So it appears that this is a thing, however, the instructions it gives is for a Raspberry Pi, and it calls for you to use raspi-config. It doesn't give anything for regular linux use. 
Using python I'm attempting to communicate between my laptop and an Up-Board. I'm connecting the Up-board by using an FTDI cable, connected to the serial connection on the board.

(OP)
I've done something similar before with C++ on a different board. The code I'm using I pulled from this site, http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/serial%20rs232%20connections%20python

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate=115200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)

print ser.isOpen()

input=1
while 1 :
        input = raw_input(">> ")
        print "Check"

        try:
                if input == 'exit':
                        ser.close()
                        exit()
                else:
                        ser.write(input + '\r\n')
                        out = ''
                        time.sleep(1)
                        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
                                out += ser.read(1)

                        if out != '':
                                print ">>" + out
        except:
                ser.close()
                break
```

I'm doing something similar on the Up-board. The only difference is that it waits for a message, then returns the message back to my laptop. Just a loop back between the Upboard and my laptop.

Here's where it gets interest.

I'm having two seperate issues.

1) I'll attempt to send a word, ie "test" and it will only send "e", "tst" doesn't get sent

2) The other issue is, it sends message, and I get a return for a password. So I reset the software and attempt to connect again, this time I send the username as the first message. I get back a reply for password, then I send the password, and now I have terminal access to the Upboard. While, all I really want is to connect to the application on the other end.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the resolution, it appears that the system was configured in grub to connect to terminal on the same port address.

if you go to /etc/default/grub you will find a line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=ttyS0, 115200n8"

I ended up commenting that line, and I now can connect without it giving me console control.